Display The Value When Submitted a number in PHP
I wrote this code in PHP to present the message if I entered any random number between 1 and 100, but when I submit the value, it doesn't display anything to me. Here is the code.
   <body>
     
        <h2>The number guess game</h2>
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <label>Enter Number:</label>
            <input type="number" name="num">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
        <div>
            <?php echo $message; ?>
        </div>
        
        <?php
            $message="";
            if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                $num = $_POST['num'];
                $random = rand(1, 100);
                if ($num == $random) {
                    $message= "You Win!";
                } else {
                    $message= "You Lose!";
                  }
             }
             else{
                echo "Enter The Number";
             }   
        ?>
     </body>



Well...your code doesn't define $message until after you've tried to echo it. So what else did you expect, and why? It can't display something that doesn't exist yet. Really you should have been getting a warning message about "undefined variable $message" instead. If you don't see that, then make sure you've enabled PHP error and warning reporting in your development environment.

Anyway it would make a lot more sense if the PHP code block was before the HTML in the file. That way it'll run as soon as a request is sent to the page, and will be able to populate $message before it's echoed, if the form has been submitted (and if not, it'll be able display "Enter the Number" above the form, which would no doubt look more sensible from the user's point of view).

$message it was defined at the beginning of php code

It was. But I'll repeat: in your code $message is defined after you try to echo it. Self-evidently you cannot display something which doesn't exist yet - that is basic logic (in all walks of life, not just programming).

I put all php code before HTML in the file, but also there is no result.

Demo 1 (problem): https://3v4l.org/u2nth , Demo 2 (fixed): https://3v4l.org/klIAH

If there's still no result when you've submitted the form, then you must have another problem as well. Enable PHP error reporting and check there are no crashes for other reasons. As per my second demo, the code will work when it's moved to the right place - when the form is submitted and $_POST is populated then it will work as designed.

<body>
    <?php
        $message="";
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $num = $_POST['num'];
            $random = rand(1, 100);
            if ($num == $random) {
                $message= "You Win!";
            } else {
                $message= "You Lose!";
              }
         }
         else{
            $message= "Enter The Number";
         }   
    ?>
    <h2>The number guess game</h2>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <label>Enter Number:</label>
        <input type="number" name="num">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
    <div>
        <?php echo $message; ?>
    </div>
    
    
 </body>

You have called your $message variable before php code is executed, so the $message variable is always blank. My code above will show message value based on post field or error message.

Unfortunately, it shows to me the message: You Lose!

print output of     print($_POST);   put this after     if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

You lose is correct as i see because if your entered number is not same as random then it will display you lose . also please confirm if this message is shown after post or by default.

The error message indicates that the PHP variable $message is being used before it is declared. This is because PHP code is executed sequentially, and if a variable is used before it is defined, it will result in an error.
To resolve this issue, the entire code block within the second <?php tags should be moved before the  tag. This will ensure that the $message variable is declared and initialized before it is used, preventing the undefined variable error.

I put the php code at the beginning, but still not working

Did you use AI to generate this answer?
